# añadir un slash "/" a directorio web

Tags: hosting

[image: Imagen que muestra la duda que tengo]

Buenas tardes, ¿cómo se le llama a ésto?
Estoy viéndolo en varias paginas web que visito y no tengo el termino adecuado para buscar en google

A la hora de crear directorios en Xampp o en mi hosting no puedo crear una carpeta que tenga este símbolo delante de el .
¿Por que?

Comment: Juan. Cuál es el propósito de agregar el slash? Al final qué es lo que quieres resolver?

Comment: poder hacerlo @PakLeiChong ,  siempre que veo algo interesante que los demas hacen trato de hacerlo entendiendo bien como se hace .

Answer (score 0):

El Slash sirve para navegar a través de una estructura de carpetas, en este caso dentro de un servidor web.Cuando uno monta un servidor web y dentro de él creamos una aplicación, es necesario establecer rutas para poder navegar entre las carpetas que constituyen esa aplicación. En los servidores existe la carpeta raíz, de la cual uno navega para llegar hasta una página específica, o bien, puede ser una dirección que contenga una petición a una base de datos.

No se puede crear una carpeta que tenga ese símbolo porque el Slash es una forma en la que indicamos un cambio en la carpeta o petición dentro de la aplicación

Comment: Hola Rodrigo , gracias por tu respuesta, mas o menos si entiendo como trabajan las rutas, lo que no entiendo es como las paginas pueden hacerlo,como puedes explicar lo de la imagen?